# 'Get over my head' and 'get in over my head'

Tags: differences

What is the difference between 'get over my head' and 'get in over my head'?  Which one to use when we are struggling to forget someone?

Comment: Neither is about forgetting.  To forget (sorta) you "get over" whatever it is.

Comment: For forgetting, you _get over_ someone. Even simpler, _I am over him_.

Answer (score -1):

*Get over my head* is either a literal spatial instruction, as in

> [This jumper was nice and snug although it was a bit of an effort to **get over my head** as it wasn't sized right.](http://www.talkgroupaustralia.com/written-by-starina--lost-socks.html)

or figurative usage meaning to recover, usually with *head* as an attributive noun:

> It will takes months of rehab therapy to **get over my head** [injury].

*To get in over my head* means to find myself in a situation that is too difficult for me to handle. The allusion is to swimming in waters too deep for my swimming abilities:

> [And, if I **get in over my head**, no worries. I am sure there will be someone there who can wave a hand for the lifeguard.](http://poststar.com/lifestyles/columns/local/petteys/in-over-my-head/article_651b87d1-b630-5df8-858d-0094fd35d32e.html)

But the phrase needn't refer to water. You can also drown in debt, among other things.

Comment: So the "Community" bumped the question to the homepage, which a driveby downvoter, a curse upon this site, took as an opportunity to display discourtesy. Is the answer right? If so, the OP is misled. If not, and it's wrong or misleading, there's no opportunity to fix it, and the OP is left in the dark. Why the "Community" puts up with this behavior is beyond me.

Comment: You are on stackexchange. Following the rules is often more important than being constructive... ;)